# How many different combinations can be put to decorate the room?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 4 identical dolls, 6 identical toys, 9 identical pillows and we can use any amount to decorate a room. In how many different ways can you decorate the room given that the room cannot be empty?

Ex)(1 doll 2 toys 3 pillows)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Please edit your post to include any attempts you have made.

Comment: Does the position of the items in the room matter?  For instance, is 1 doll (on the bed) the same as 1 doll (on the chair)?

Answer (score 2):

How many choices are there for the number of dolls?  For each of the other items?  Now multiply, and subtract the one choice of none of any of them.